# template can't deduce type

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code, works fine.

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
T somefunc(typename Iterator first, typename Iterator last, T init)
{
    return init;
}
class test
{
public:
    template<typename callbackA, typename callbackB>
    void runtest(callbackA callbackp, callbackB callbackn)
    {
        v.reserve(10);
        int init = 0;
        callbackp(v.begin(), v.end(), init);
        callbackn(v.begin(), v.end(), init);
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};


auto main() -> int 
{

    test t;
    t.runtest(std::bind(somefunc<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3),
        std::bind(somefunc<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
}
```

Then I try to turn class test into a template

```
  template<typename Container>
    class test
    {
    public:
        
        template<typename callbackA, typename callbackB>
        void runtest(callbackA callbackp, callbackB callbackn)
        {
            v.reserve(10);
            int init = 0;
            callbackp(v.begin(), v.end(), init);
            callbackn(v.begin(), v.end(), init);
        }
    private:
        Container v;
    };
```

then i get a compile error: can't match overload function: iterator can't convert to placeholder, at this line:callbackp(v.begin(), v.end(), init);  i think it's can't deduce type itself
then i try to make the class to this:

```
template<template<typename> class Container, typename T>
```

or try to change the declare of somefunc to this:

```
template<typename Container, typename T>
 T somefunc(typename Container::iterator first, typename Container::iterator last, T init)
```

I get the same error.

how to fix this. thanks.

Comment: When you turned `test` into a template did you change anything in `main()` as well?

Comment: @0x499602D2 sure i did. the error is the same, not can't instance  not provide parameter

Comment: Show us the updated main, please.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sorry, I found the reason, when i change code, i change it from the original code, not this minimal code, the real code, i declare that container as const.sorry.

Comment: Works as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0a27713dacf4bc)